# How to implement image map type interface for a game board in Java 6

Tags: java, imagemap

My group project at school is to implement a style of monopoly in which students can buy courses and land on various squares and move around the board. This is not a regular square board so we were wondering if anyone had any ideas on how we would implement an image map or something like it to create many clickable regions not in a perfect square. I have attached the image of the game board. Just a way to start is needed, not lots of code or anything as we all know java pretty well. If anyone has any ideas that would be great.

Image of board is here.

[image: http://imgur.com/fH5WC.png]

Comment: Hi Are you constrained to use Java? If not consider JavaFX; new UI technology, and allows to easily convert SVG or adobe PS files to scene graphs

Comment: Are you doing this on the web or desktop?  If web, are you using any framework?

Answer (score 0):

Java image maps can have polygonal clickable regions.  As usual, Sun has an [excellent tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnavm.html).